# How to NewComer items slider creat custom with out shopingworld?

Tags: shopware

I want to add Newcome slider at homepage but without using shopping world. Is it anyway to access?
If You have an answer, please Provide to me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way by default, but you can write plugin, which create new widget and extend template where you want to add this slider.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply.

Comment: I have the second question. I have created a sub shop and also a different theme for this shop. My question is if I can switch a sub shop but how can enable theme? Because the default Shop theme already switches.

Comment: @AmitSenjalija I'm not sure I understand your question, but you can select theme in theme manager like on screenshot: http://joxi.ru/LmGeBL9HwRqEEA
If you want to create new theme - please check this guide: https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/theme-startup-guide/
You can use the same theme for different subshops with different logo e.t.c: https://en.shopware.com/news/shopware-5-series-the-new-theme-manager/

Comment: I have created a theme which extended by responsive theme but I want to remove all less file in a responsive theme so I have had to add following line into the **theme.php**: `protected $discardedLessThemes = [\Shopware\Themes\Responsive\Theme::class];`  While compiling theme this error ocurrs like this: variable @desktopViewportWidth is undefined

Comment: @AmitSenjalija, I'm sorry I can't help you. I'm not sure it's right way. You can recreate all less components and in this case, as far as I know, you will got empty theme.

Comment: Hey, @Alexey Palamar,
I have one question about **shop page** ,  I have added a free text field in shop page via backend and field is media field and added one image. But when check to debug image path not found only show media id So how to render an image in a template.
http://prntscr.com/koii98